# Can't get Storage class to work for GWT?

Tags: gwt

I'd like to use the Storage class with GWT. I have this in my projectname.gwt.xml file:

```
<module rename-to='projectname'>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.storage.client.Storage' />

    ...
```

but starting the project in dev mode throws:

```
Loading modules
  com.me.myproject
  Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.storage.client.Storage'
     [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/google/gwt/storage/client/Storage.gwt.xml' 
     on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a 
     classpath entry for source?
  [ERROR] Line 5: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
```

is there an additional jar or something we need to include to get it to work?

Thanks

Comment: Did you [read the documentation](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage)? I don't think you're supposed to inherit it as a module.

Comment: Argh correct - I read that as needing it as a module import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gwt xml file for storage is located at:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.storage.Storage' />
```

remove the client from your import and you should be fine